# Nginx Reverse Proxy with WSO2 ESB giving Forbidden 403

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-status-code-403, wso2-esb

I am a newbie when it comes to configuring the Nginx Reverse Proxy on cloud. So, I need help in configuration of Reverse proxy to WSO2 ESB server. So far, I have been able to follow online tutorials and come up with configuration like this.

```
         server {
           listen 443;
           server_name  server.nginx.com;
           ssl on;
           ssl_certificate nginx.crt;
           ssl_certificate_key nginx.key;
        location /esb {
           index index.html;
           root jsp;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_pass https://esb.server.com:9446;
   proxy_redirect  https://esb.server.com:9446  https://server.nginx.com/esb;
          #proxy_redirect off;
          # proxy_cookie_path / /esb/;
        }
    }
```

With this configuration I am able to get the login screen. But whenever I try to log in I get an error 403 forbidden on the login_action.jsp. I have given 755 permission on the directory where wso2 ESB is installed to no avail. Attached below screenshot.

[403 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQxhj.png)

Kindly help me in this regard if you have ever come across the same issue.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This 403 error is occur due to the jdk latest version so the problem caused on the java environment .so install the jdk 7

Comment: Hi, it is actually due to the following check being performed at esb level. So i went to this location (/esb/wso2esb-5.0.0/repository/conf/security/Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties) and then  I disabled this property. 
org.owasp.csrfguard.Enabled = false

I know this leaves a security loophole. But this was what i could do. 
We also have JAVA version 1.8. So I could definitely loop back but. I also have some other servers running which need the latest version.